# Java web server can listen to requests but not send responses

Tags: java, server, request, webserver

This is part of the program that is having trouble.

```java
public void run() {

    while(!isStopped) {

        try {

            socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " has connected");

            //problem starts
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String request;
            while((request = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(request);
            } //problem ends

            FileReader f = new FileReader("html/index.html");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
            String response;

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
            out.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n");
            out.write("\r\n");
            while((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(response);
            }

            out.close();
            socket.close();


        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I created a java web server and it works fine with all the connections. But when the program listens to the request from client and print that request on the console, the program doesn't continue and so it doesn't respond with the HTML file. I tried getting rid of the printing the request part and the program easily sends the HTML but I don't like that because it doesn't print the initial request. How can I make the server properly listen and print client requests and send responses back accordingly and continue like this in a loop? It would be great to show the codes.

Comment: So you are trying to put all the developers at `tomcat` out of work? so easy ?

Comment: You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP,  and none of it is exhibited here. For a start, the request is not terminated by end of stream. Have a look at the Content-length and Transfer-encoding provisions before you proceed.

Comment: Duplicate of [readLine() loop not exiting until remote client closes connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39949382/207421).

Comment: @ScaryWombat What's the problem? I'm just doing this for academic purposes and I'm still only a month into programming.

Comment: No problem. As per @EJP if it is for academic purpose then study the HTTProtocol